# JavaScript Number and bitwise operations

Tags: javascript, numbers, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I know that JS `Number` types are IEEE754 double precision floating points.
Given this fact, how does JS perform bitwise operations?

```js
-1 >>> 1
=> 2147483647
```

Is it merely simulating bitwise operations programmatically or does the language actually have a special treatment for bitwise operations, like when using bitwise, load numbers on registers as `Int32` bit pattern, etc.?

I'm not nit picky about performance, but given that bitwise operations are known to be efficient and often used for that reason, I'm wondering about the internals here.

Comment: Yes, it just converts them (u)int32

Comment: @Bergi Converts them where?

Comment: In the specified semantics of the language… The operands are evaluated, coerced to numbers, those are converted to integers, the integers are operated on, the result integer is converted back to a number and returned as the expression result.

Comment: Of course how an actual engine does implement these semantics is a totally different question. It might never have started with a floating point number, representing it as an integer internally in memory already as long as it doesn't leave the integer range. The optimisation possibilities are endless.

Comment: So it seems like the real answer to this question is "it depends on the implementation of the interpreter." I was actually wondering about that. Thanks.

Comment: It just seemed a little weird coming from a strongly-typed language background that you can perform bitwise operations on a double.

Comment: It's well-defined how the bitwise operators need to behave so all implementations will have the same results, but yes, if you are looking at the register level it always depends on the interpreter/compiler (and even processor architecture), just like in any other language higher than assembly.

Comment: Well, given that bitwise operators are supposed to (or maybe expected to) operate on bit patterns, I don't think it's weird to think that what is known to be a double-precision format performs bit-shifts like it's an int32. You can't expect exponent bias bit patterns' bit-shift to give any meaningful numeric results like a two's complement bit pattern does.